# PHP error exposes database credentials

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, database-connection

I've been working with a PHP application that connects to a MySQL database using PDO. Whenever there's a fault in the connection we get an error like this:

[image: PHP PDO Error]

This often happens when updating server details or when adding a new server to the cluster, and is occasionally visible to end-users. I'm particularly concerned as the resulting error exposes connection details used for the database. Is it possible to change the error reporting so that we show what the error is without including the connection details themselves?

Comment: Do you have xdebug installed on these servers?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what , you are looking for ?

```
try {
    $rs = $db->prepare('query_here');
    $rs->execute();
    $foo = $rs->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Oh noes! There's an error in the query!");
}
```

In production, if you cannot access "php.ini" file, than set `error_reporting(0)`, and if you can edit "php.ini" file than set `display_errors = off`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice not to display any php errors when not under developement. You can log them instead.

You can use theese commands or write it by hand into php.ini file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'your custom log file (optional)');
```

Also you should use **try catch** block every time you query the database

```
try {
    //query the database here
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    trigger_error('your error here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try/catch the exception and change the message but you SHOULD not show errors on production ! you can set display_errors = off in your php.ini file or by adding this:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: Why error_reporting(0) ? if you dont display errors anyway? That's not good